# Using Java, I am unable to sort a list of alpha numeric elements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I declared an ArrayList like:

```
ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I filled this list by reading a column from an HTML table like this:

```
for(int rnum=1;rnum<(rows.size())+1;rnum++) 
{
 columns.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/table/tbody/tr[" + rnum + "]/td[1]")).getText());
}
```

Then I need to sort this list, and I used this:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(rows);
```

But this is not sorting the ArrayList.

Please note that my ArrayList contains text with alphabets, numeric values and special characters like : Testing123@, SampleTest123, Lasttest@1 etc.

Comment: Why do you think that sorting `rows` would affect the order of `columns`?

Comment: If you want to sort `columns`, call `Collections.sort` with that `List`. `Collections.sort(columns)`.

Comment: I think you are sorting the wrong list . You are adding your HTML content in the 'columns' list and you are sorting the 'rows' list. What exactly do you want to achieve here.

Comment: Actually in another line of code, i am reading no of rows of html table . That's why i have used rows.size().

Comment: Gonzo - Collections.sort(columns) doesn't work as mentioned above.

Comment: kindly replace 'rows' by 'columns' wherever used

Comment: @user3196663 please specify what you mean by "doesn't work as mentioned above" - see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List) - the signature of Collections.sort with only the list argument sorts the elements according to the "natural" order - which in the case of String is the lexical order. If you want another order, there's another signature which takes a comparatoer as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sort called [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

**AlphanumComparator.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator
{
    private final boolean isDigit(char ch)
    {
        return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
    }

    private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker)
    {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(marker);
        chunk.append(c);
        marker++;
        if (isDigit(c))
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (!isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        } else
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        if (!(o1 instanceof String) || !(o2 instanceof String))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        String s1 = (String)o1;
        String s2 = (String)o2;

        int thisMarker = 0;
        int thatMarker = 0;
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();

        while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length)
        {
            String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
            thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

            String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
            thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

            int result = 0;
            if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0)))
            {
                int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
                result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++)
                    {
                        result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                        if (result != 0)
                        {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
            }

            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }

        return s1Length - s2Length;
    }
}
```

Which would then be called

```
java.util.Collections.sort(columns, new AlphanumComparator());
```

You can check if it worked by using

```
System.out.println(columns.toString);
```